# Android Time class: is it locally linear with milliseconds?

Tags: android, time

By this I mean:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
long millis = time.toMillis(false);
time.monthDay++;
```

is

```
time.toMillis(false) == millis + 24l*3600*1000
```

always true?

the same question with

```
time.hour++;
```

for I think the time system is extremely complex, I do not know what is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#toMillis%28boolean%29) for `public long toMillis (boolean ignoreDst)` you should use `toMillis(true)` after adding or subtracting days or explicitly setting the "monthDay" field. On the other hand, if you are adding or subtracting hours or minutes, then you should use `toMillis(false)`.

You should also use `toMillis(false)` if you want to read back the same milliseconds that you set with `set(long)` or `set(Time)` or after parsing a date string.

look to `public int isDst()` for more information concerning `ignoreDst`:

This time is in daylight savings time. One of:

   positive - in dst

   0 - not in dst

   negative - unknown